# Extremely long-lasting query

Tags: arangodb, aql

Is it possible that this query is not well query-optimized, and has somebody possibly a hint for me how to make it better? Currently it lasts hours before I kill it.

### Figures:

- collection with less than 2 million small records (need 2 GB RAM)
- having 16 indexes (which need 1.2 GB RAM)

arangosh [SES]> db.AuditsSearch.figures()

```
{
  "alive" : {
    "count" : 1940004,
    "size" : 2052009624
  },
  "dead" : {
    "count" : 397017,
"size" : 431456792,
"deletion" : 52950
  },
  "datafiles" : {
    "count" : 20,
    "fileSize" : 2132549880
  },
  "journals" : {
    "count" : 1,
    "fileSize" : 67108864
  },
  "compactors" : {
    "count" : 1,
    "fileSize" : 256528080
  },
  "shapefiles" : {
    "count" : 0,
    "fileSize" : 0
  },
  "shapes" : {
    "count" : 1004,
    "size" : 1310704
  },
  "attributes" : {
    "count" : 65,
    "size" : 3408
  },
  "indexes" : {
    "count" : 16,
    "size" : 1198718256
  },
  "lastTick" : "14686717826252",
  "uncollectedLogfileEntries" : 0
}
```

### Query:

```
FOR a IN AuditsSearch

  // split the task as it currently is not possible to execute at once:
  FILTER IS_NULL(a.analytics)
  LIMIT 200000, 200000
  // end of split ... which also does not work

    LET utcTimestamp = DATE_TIMESTAMP(a.timestamp)
    LET intNumResults = TO_NUMBER(a.resultcount)
    LET intDuration = TO_NUMBER(a.duration)
    LET url = SPLIT(a.docid, "|")[1]

UPDATE a WITH { "analytics": { "utcTimestamp": utcTimestamp, "duration": intDuration, "numResults": intNumResults, "url": url } } IN AuditsSearch
```

### Indexes:

```
[
{"id":"AuditsSearch/0","type":"primary","unique":true,"fields":["_key"]},
{"id":"AuditsSearch/13943073289094","type":"hash","unique":false,"fields":["eventtype"]},
{"id":"AuditsSearch/13943144067974","type":"hash","unique":false,"fields":["profile"]},
{"id":"AuditsSearch/13943163138950","type":"hash","unique":false,"fields":["sessionid"]},
{"id":"AuditsSearch/13943169299334","type":"hash","unique":false,"fields":["resultid"]},
{"id":"AuditsSearch/13943195644806","type":"skiplist","unique":false,"fields":["duration"]},
{"id":"AuditsSearch/13947101328262","type":"skiplist","unique":false,"fields":["timestamp"]},
{"id":"AuditsSearch/14023678636934","type":"skiplist","unique":false,"fields":["analytics.utcTimestamp"]},
{"id":"AuditsSearch/14064254132425","type":"skiplist","unique":false,"fields":["resultcount"]},
{"id":"AuditsSearch/14101960466633","type":"skiplist","unique":false,"fields":["analytics.duration"]},
{"id":"AuditsSearch/14101968134345","type":"skiplist","unique":false,"fields":["analytics.numResults"]},
{"id":"AuditsSearch/14140104909001","type":"hash","unique":false,"fields":["analytics.url"]},
{"id":"AuditsSearch/14168504672457","type":"skiplist","unique":false,"fields":["sessionid"]},
{"id":"AuditsSearch/14168754823369","type":"skiplist","unique":false,"fields":["eventtype"]},
{"id":"AuditsSearch/14169726263497","type":"hash","unique":false,"fields":["isadmin"]},
{"id":"AuditsSearch/14169732554953","type":"hash","unique":false,"fields":["isdelegatedadmin"]}
]
```

### Execution Plan:

```
{
  "plan": {
    "nodes": [{
      "type": "SingletonNode",
      "dependencies": [],
      "id": 1,
      "estimatedCost": 1,
      "estimatedNrItems": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "EnumerateCollectionNode",
      "dependencies": [1],
      "id": 2,
      "estimatedCost": 1704564,
      "estimatedNrItems": 1704563,
      "database": "SES",
      "collection": "AuditsSearch",
      "outVariable": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "a"
      },
      "random": false
    },
    {
      "type": "CalculationNode",
      "dependencies": [2],
      "id": 3,
      "estimatedCost": 3409127,
      "estimatedNrItems": 1704563,
      "expression": {
        "type": "function call",
        "name": "IS_NULL",
        "subNodes": [{
          "type": "array",
          "subNodes": [{
            "type": "attribute access",
            "name": "analytics",
            "subNodes": [{
              "type": "reference",
              "name": "a",
              "id": 0
            }]
          }]
        }]
      },
      "outVariable": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "5"
      },
      "canThrow": false
    },
    {
      "type": "FilterNode",
      "dependencies": [3],
      "id": 4,
      "estimatedCost": 5113690,
      "estimatedNrItems": 1704563,
      "inVariable": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "5"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "CalculationNode",
      "dependencies": [4],
      "id": 6,
      "estimatedCost": 6818253,
      "estimatedNrItems": 1704563,
      "expression": {
        "type": "function call",
        "name": "DATE_TIMESTAMP",
        "subNodes": [{
          "type": "array",
          "subNodes": [{
            "type": "attribute access",
            "name": "timestamp",
            "subNodes": [{
              "type": "reference",
              "name": "a",
              "id": 0
            }]
          }]
        }]
      },
      "outVariable": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "utcTimestamp"
      },
      "canThrow": false
    },
    {
      "type": "CalculationNode",
      "dependencies": [6],
      "id": 7,
      "estimatedCost": 8522816,
      "estimatedNrItems": 1704563,
      "expression": {
        "type": "function call",
        "name": "TO_NUMBER",
        "subNodes": [{
          "type": "array",
          "subNodes": [{
            "type": "attribute access",
            "name": "resultcount",
            "subNodes": [{
              "type": "reference",
              "name": "a",
              "id": 0
            }]
          }]
        }]
      },
      "outVariable": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "intNumResults"
      },
      "canThrow": false
    },
    {
      "type": "CalculationNode",
      "dependencies": [7],
      "id": 8,
      "estimatedCost": 10227379,
      "estimatedNrItems": 1704563,
      "expression": {
        "type": "function call",
        "name": "TO_NUMBER",
        "subNodes": [{
          "type": "array",
          "subNodes": [{
            "type": "attribute access",
            "name": "duration",
            "subNodes": [{
              "type": "reference",
              "name": "a",
              "id": 0
            }]
          }]
        }]
      },
      "outVariable": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "intDuration"
      },
      "canThrow": false
    },
    {
      "type": "CalculationNode",
      "dependencies": [8],
      "id": 9,
      "estimatedCost": 11931942,
      "estimatedNrItems": 1704563,
      "expression": {
        "type": "indexed access",
        "subNodes": [{
          "type": "function call",
          "name": "SPLIT",
          "subNodes": [{
            "type": "array",
            "subNodes": [{
              "type": "attribute access",
              "name": "docid",
              "subNodes": [{
                "type": "reference",
                "name": "a",
                "id": 0
              }]
            },
            {
              "type": "value",
              "value": "|"
            }]
          }]
        },
        {
          "type": "value",
          "value": 1
        }]
      },
      "outVariable": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "url"
      },
      "canThrow": false
    },
    {
      "type": "CalculationNode",
      "dependencies": [9],
      "id": 10,
      "estimatedCost": 13636505,
      "estimatedNrItems": 1704563,
      "expression": {
        "type": "object",
        "subNodes": [{
          "type": "object element",
          "name": "analytics",
          "subNodes": [{
            "type": "object",
            "subNodes": [{
              "type": "object element",
              "name": "utcTimestamp",
              "subNodes": [{
                "type": "reference",
                "name": "utcTimestamp",
                "id": 1
              }]
            },
            {
              "type": "object element",
              "name": "duration",
              "subNodes": [{
                "type": "reference",
                "name": "intDuration",
                "id": 3
              }]
            },
            {
              "type": "object element",
              "name": "numResults",
              "subNodes": [{
                "type": "reference",
                "name": "intNumResults",
                "id": 2
              }]
            },
            {
              "type": "object element",
              "name": "url",
              "subNodes": [{
                "type": "reference",
                "name": "url",
                "id": 4
              }]
            }]
          }]
        }]
      },
      "outVariable": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "6"
      },
      "canThrow": false
    },
    {
      "type": "LimitNode",
      "dependencies": [10],
      "id": 5,
      "estimatedCost": 13836505,
      "estimatedNrItems": 200000,
      "offset": 0,
      "limit": 200000,
      "fullCount": false
    },
    {
      "type": "UpdateNode",
      "dependencies": [5],
      "id": 11,
      "estimatedCost": 14036505,
      "estimatedNrItems": 0,
      "inDocVariable": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "6"
      },
      "database": "SES",
      "collection": "AuditsSearch",
      "modificationFlags": {
        "ignoreErrors": false,
        "waitForSync": false,
        "nullMeansRemove": false,
        "mergeObjects": true,
        "ignoreDocumentNotFound": false
      },
      "inKeyVariable": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "a"
      }
    }],
    "rules": ["move-calculations-up",
    "move-filters-up",
    "move-calculations-up-2",
    "move-filters-up-2"],
    "collections": [{
      "name": "AuditsSearch",
      "type": "write"
    }],
    "variables": [{
      "id": 0,
      "name": "a"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "utcTimestamp"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "url"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "intNumResults"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "intDuration"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "6"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "5"
    }],
    "estimatedCost": 14036505,
    "estimatedNrItems": 0
  },
  "warnings": [],
  "stats": {
    "rulesExecuted": 19,
    "rulesSkipped": 0,
    "plansCreated": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: How long does the query take if you turn the `UPDATE a WITH...` into a `RETURN a`? If that's fast, then it's probably the `UPDATE` part taking long. As the update is using the primary key, it could be the amount of indexes that's causing the delay. How long does it take to execute without the extra indexes? If the indexes are not very selective, this could also cause delays because it takes longer to find the relevant index entries.

Comment: Good hints, thanks. My observations up to now are:

Comment: 1.) in the execution plan I see that the LET-Statements will be done before the FILTER/LIMITs,
    does that sound reasonable?
2.) Readonly queries (RETURN ..) are finished within a few seconds
3.) Doing the updates in a volatile collection without indexes also runs within a few seconds
4.) making again a fresh collection with all the indexes unfortunately leads to a response time of maybe hours
   instead of secondes.
5.) deleting all indexes .... YES, now also the UPDATE runs within seconds.

OK, index updates cost a few additional percent of runtime.
But hours instead of seconds?

Comment: Another test: I've reduced the amount of indexes to "only" the 8 hash indexes. But the UPDATE queries still are very, very slow (I killed the job after 10 minutes)

Comment: Hm. 1 index is enough to slow the UPDATE statements down form a few seconds to "endless" > 10 minutes. When I delete all indexes, it again runs in seconds. Creating any of those indexes --> endless. So, what is the system-internal difference between an update with and without index?

Comment: Another observation is: if I execute an AQL with a large amounts of record INSERTs into a volatile collection, and - in a second step - from there into a persistent collection with indexes, it runs extremely faster than if I do the same directly into that same persistent collection. But shouldn't the calculation effort be comparable?

Comment: I think the indexes (or at least one of them) will not be very selective, and that this causes the slowdown. The non-unique hash index does have an amortized cost of O(1) for inserts (so index creation is still fast), but for updates/deletes, it needs to find the "right" element among the ones with identical keys. When there are many index entries with the same key, finding the "correct" item will take up to n comparisons (with n being the number of items with the same key). The unique hash index of course does not have this problem, but a non-unique one with many identical keys will show it.

Comment: Yes, that's a very reasonable answer. I will do some tests into this direction. THANKS. One thing left: Do you think it might make sense to check the optimization plans according to my observation 1) ?

Comment: If observation 1.) was about the `LET` statements being pulled before the `FILTER`s/`LIMIT`s and this causing potentially unnecessary calculations, then this has been addressed already for 2.5. I happened to write a blog post about this here: http://jsteemann.github.io/blog/2015/01/31/yaor-yet-another-optimizer-rule/

Comment: Sounds great, and the optimization figures in your blog post are impressing! Concerning your explanation about indexes slowing down UPDATE actions, I made a new observation: It even takes hours to truncate the whole index at once. In this case, no singular index updates could be the reason I think, as in this case simply everything could be thrown away without further calucations? But well, even this operation takes hours. Any ideas on that observation?

Comment: The reason for this is that `truncate()` will remove every single document, and this will search and remove every single document in the index. If the index is not very selective (e.g. if all keys are identical or there are very few distinct keys), finding the *right* document and deleting it from the index will be very slow. Insertion into the index is amorting O(1), but updating and deleting is O(n) where n is the number of items with the same key value.

Comment: If truncate is implemented that way, hat explains the behavior, of course. To be honest, I didn't have expected that, as in my naïve understanding, truncate simply could throw away everything at once. Wouldn't the result be the same? Or is there another reason for this one-by-one-cycles?

Comment: The `truncate` is a transactional operation. If it fails somewhere in the middle, it can recover and restore the documents. Therefore it is about the same as looping over all documents in a collection and removing them one-by-one.

Comment: Does the problem still persist? or can we close this issue?

Comment: Please close this issue - thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the key takeaways from the discussion above:

Nowadays you should use `db._explain(<your aql query goes here>)` instead of fetching the raw execution plan. Some of the experienced behaviours have been improved in newer arangodb versions.

- [The optimizer isn't always perfect in its decisions, but its improving](http://jsteemann.github.io/blog/2015/01/31/yaor-yet-another-optimizer-rule/). The experienced LET pull before filters is now detected by the optimizer and avoided. The ArangoDB team is always keen on learning about your queries therefore.
- If you want to know which parts of a complex query cause high resource usage it may be usefull to split it and try the bits measuring their time.
- sometimes it makes sense to use a temporary volatile collection.
- index maintainance is costly. If you plan to move large amounts of documents, it may make sense to drop the indices and recreate them afterwards.
- non-uniq hash indices may need much performance if their selectivity is goes bad; meaning that if you have lots of hash collisions or duplicate keys cost for index usage goes up both at insert and at query time.
- The non-unique hash index does have an amortized cost of O(1) for inserts (so index creation is still fast), but for updates/deletes, it needs to find the "right" element among the ones with identical keys. When there are many index entries with the same key, finding the "correct" item will take up to *n* comparisons (with n being the number of items with the same key). The unique hash index of course does not have this problem, but a non-unique one with many identical keys will show it.
- having many indices sums up aforementioned overhead on index maintenance.
- `truncate()` involves index maintenance. You may want to drop the index and recreate it.